# How to get XML's resources in Kotlin code when cannot find context?

Tags: kotlin, android-resources

A button's text switchs OK/Canel depends on its `onClickListener()`.

"OK" and "Cancel" was defined in both code and XML, how to define them at one place?

I tried to use `btnText.value = application.resources.getString(R.string.cancel)`.

However, **application** can only be found inside `init{}` in `viewModel.class`.

In `viewModel.class`:

```
class xxxViewModel(application: Application, ...

    val btnText = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun funForListener(){
        if (condition) btnText.value ="OK"
        else btnText.value ="Cancel"

        // error, cannot find application
        btnText.value = application.resources.getString(R.string.cancel)
    }
     
    init{
        // no error
        btnText.value = application.resources.getString(R.string.cancel)
    }
```

In res/strings.xml:

```
<string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="ok">OK</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary constructor is not declaring properties, but just receiving parameters. These can only be used in the `init` block. Use

```
class xxxViewModel(val application: Application, ...)
```

instead to define an `application` property in the `xxxViewModel` class

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

Comment: I did not use 'val application', syntax error somehow, still used 'application', then add 'private val context = application', it works now.